# XML namespaces architecture: Common / Shared, Request / Input, Response / Output

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xml-namespaces

I'm working on XML Schemas (XSD) for my application for 1) input (request) and 2) output (response) data. Input and output data structures share some Complex- and SimpleType that are used in *both* input and output data structures.

My approach is: I have a `common.xsd` that I **include** in both `input.xsd` and `output.xsd`. As I use `include` (instead of `import`), all schemas share a single XML **namespace**, e.g.

```
http://example.org/MyApplication
```

`common.xsd` does not declare any elements, only types. The actual elements are defined in `input.xsd` and `output.xsd`.

Should I have different namespaces for all 3 schemas? E.g.

- `http://example.org/MyApplication/common`,
- `http://example.org/MyApplication/request`,
- `http://example.org/MyApplication/response` ?

What are the implications or pros/cons of having a) a shared namespace for all schemas and b) different namespaces for these schemas? I'm not sure what's the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

My inclination would be to use a single namespace for all three. It makes it easier to re-use definitions across different parts of the application.

There are only really two good reasons for using multiple namespaces: (a) there is a very real prospect of local names clashing, and/or (b) different vocabularies are defined by different naming authorities and there's no overall point of change control.

To be honest though, this is too big a question for a simple Q&A on Stack Overflow. I once spent months consulting with a large bank that was struggling with how to design schemas and namespaces for 400 different message types that were being used for data interchange within the organisation - which of course had a lot of shared parts, often with variations for different messages - and the bottom line is that there is no easy answer. But what I learnt from the exercise is that it all depends how you want to manage change. If control is very decentralised, go for separate namespaces and schemas; if you want to maximise integration and reuse, go for a single namespace that embraces everything.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response! Are you aware of XML libraries that would get confused if the same namespace identifier `http://example.org/MyApp` points to different xml schemas, e.g. `input.xsd` and `output.xsd` depending on the XML document to be validated? `<input xmlns="http://example.org/MyApp" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.org/MyApp myappInput.xsd ">...</input>` vs. different files with `<output xmlns="http://example.org/MyApp" xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.org/MyApp myappOutput.xsd "></output>`

Comment: So long as there are no conflicts between input.xsd and output.xsd - that is, so long as they can be combined together into a single schema that embraces both - then it shouldn't be a problem.